# Advanced box plots in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, boxplot, data-science

I am currently exploring Tableau and I wonder if it can do the following.

Let's say I have a table with two columns, A and B. Let's say A can attain discrete values from a small set (maybe 10 different values), while B has continuous values. I would like to plot a box plot where on the x-axis are the 10 possible values of A, and on the y-axis the box plots. Each box plot shall contain values from B for a given value of A.

In case I have not made myself clear enough, here is an example. Consider data containing average temperature on each day within one year, labeled by week days. That is, we have 365 pairs (A, B), where A is a value between 1 to 7 (day of week), and B is the temperature. I would like to have 7 box plots, each containing data for the particular day week. (To prove that on Mondays there is always bad weather :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the problem slightly to assume the columns are named Date and Temp, and that Date is a real date with a month, day and year. On the data pane (left margin), make sure the Date field is a discrete (blue) dimension with datatype date (not string).

Drag Temp to rows, make sure it is a continuous measure. I would choose the aggregation function AVG instead of Sum for temperatures.

Change the mark type from automatic to circle, and then drag Date to the detail shelf. Right click on the Date pill you just dropped and choose Exact Date.

Change to the Analysis table and drag in box plot from the Summary section. Format to taste.

To get one column per weekday, drag Date onto the columns shelf. Right click on the Date field on the columns shelf and choose Weekday from the context menu (submenu)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! The first two paragraphs worked fine. In the third one, the Temp pill didn't have 'Exact Date'. (Is it because it's a temperature and not a date?) Then, box plot in the Analysis tab was greyed out. Probably because the previous step didn't work?

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out (just had to replace Temp by Date in the third paragraph) and allowed myself to edit your answer.